# How i can split "\n" in haskell?

Tags: haskell

i have the following text as String:

```
1. INTRODUCTION
Cerebral venous sinus thrombosis (CVST)
```

and i only need the second line as string, so i am using the below code

```
let SecondLine = unwords( tail (splitOn "\n" seccion))
```

but SecondLine is empty. Someone can help me?

Comment: The line of code can't compile. `splitOn` is of type `Text -> Text -> [Text]` and `unwords` are of type `[String] -> String`. Your are handing `unwords` a wrong type. Could you copy the entire function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried to use `lines`?

```
let secondLine = (lines seccion) !! 1 in
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution to dropping the first line is to uses `lines`. It has the following signatures:

```
lines :: String -> [String]   -- Splits string over newline character
```

You can therefore get the second line using:

```
let secondLine = head (tail (lines seccion))
```

Alternatively, you can use point-free style:

```
let secondLine = head . tail . lines $ seccion
```

Answer (score 1):

or simply

```
let (header:second:rest) = lines seccion
```

Comment: `let (_:second:_) = lines seccion in`